# How to turn multiple graph equations into a single equations?

Tags: graphing-functions

Say I have this equation:
$$x^2=y \quad y^3=x \quad x=y^{1/2}$$

and say I wanted to turn them into a single equation so they will be graphed from just one equation.
I tried multiplying them and making them equal to zero, no hope.
I even tried to search "super-imposing" on Google, no help.

Comment: Are you trying to just plot them on the same axis? In what software? If by hand, just do it...

Comment: online graphing sites (desmos.com etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. This post explains how to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 2):

So you have a system of equations
$$x^2=y \quad y^3=x \quad x=y^{1/2}$$
and I understand that you want *one* equation with the same solution set as this system. What you can do is: $$(x^2-y)^2+(y^3-x)^2+(x-y^{1/2})^2=0$$
Assuming only real numbers, this equation is solved if and only if all three terms are zero, which is exactly your system of equations.

Comment: but what if I multiplied the equations by sqrt(|x|/x)? will it break?